# How to convert BigInteger to Hex of fixed length?

Tags: java, hex, type-conversion, biginteger

BigInteger.toString(16) does the work but sometimes the number of bytes of the hex varies. I need exactly 512 bytes hex everytime. I have also tried apache's Hex and DataTypeConverter and more. But none guarantees this consistency. Is there any other Java library available to generate a fixed length hex from a given BigInteger?

PS: I have searched stackoverflow before posting but found no discussion dealing with Fixed length hex issue.

Comment: Have you tried a format like `"%0512x"`?

Comment: I guess you mean 'chars' not 'bytes'. And of course 512 hex chars is a lot, but how would you guarantee that length if the value is in fact too large to fit into 512 chars?

Comment: @GhostCat actually it is hex of a privateKey-exponent whose bit length is around 2048. That's why it's large.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As given in comments, use `String s = String.format("%0512x", BigInteger.valueOf(theNumber))`

Formatter does support BigInteger: see its documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dnbint).

Comment: Will this evaluate hex of the BigInteger?

Comment: @Pratap Please read **carefully**. There is a **link** in that answer pointing to the documentation of **formatting** patterns. Don't ask questions for stuff that is already answered. Just read the answer ... as often as it takes to understand it ;-) ... and understand: BigInteger is just a numerical VALUE. How a string looks like that is generated out of that value has nothing to do with the value itself. BigInteger isnt "hex" (or not-hex), it is a number. Hex comes in when you format the value as string!

Comment: @EmmanuelLonca thanks for the solution. Worked like a charm with a minor change.    'String s = String.format("%0512x", bigIntegerNumber)'.

Comment: @GhostCat sorry I missed the link. I didnt understand the documentation in 1st go and had to go through several other links to get a grip. Finally I did! Thanks for the explanation and for being patient with me :)

Comment: You are welcome ... that is what we are here for ;-)